# Get objectId from just added object (parse.com)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I am adding a object to a class called "house". I immediately want to grab the objectId of that object to update another class. How would I go about this? My code is currently:

```
PFObject *addHouse = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"House"];
            addHouse[@"houseName"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s House", obj.name];
            [addHouse saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[addHouse saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
 {
     if (succeeded)
     {
       NSLog(@"%@",addHouse.objectId);
     }

 }];
```

I hope to be useful

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you (might want to add a semi-colon on the end of the NSLog though)